# Microsoft Graph - Retrieving invalid contact email address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If an Office 365 contact's email address is invalid (ex: `user@example?com`), how do I retrieve the the email address with Microsoft Graph?

I've tried `/contacts` and `/contacts/{id}`. The first returns an empty `address`:

```
 "emailAddresses": [
     {
         "name": "name",
         "address": ""
     }
 ]
```

and the second simply omits it:

```
 "emailAddresses": [
     {
         "name": "name"
     }
 ]
```

Edit: By "contact" I mean Outlook contacts accessible in the Office 365 People app, not regular Office 365 users. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [an issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2151) on Github that solved my problem.

Turns out an Exchange contact's (first) [`EmailAddress`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/emailaddress) has an hidden [`PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179197(v=exchg.80).aspx) in addition to its `address`.
When you set the email address to an invalid one, the invalid address is stored in the `OriginalDisplayName` and its `address` is cleared, which is the reason the contact's email address is `(Empty)` in Office 365 People's contact list but the invalid address seems to still be there when you edit the contact.

`PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName` is an MAPI property. In order to obtain it, we need to use [extended properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview). The request should look like below but with the spaces URL-encoded to `%20`:

```
GET /me/contacts/{id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8084')
```

The response should include an additional field containing the invalid address:

```
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "id": "String {00062004-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8084",
        "value": "user@example?com"
    }
```

If the contact has multiple email addresses, use `PidLidEmail2OriginalDisplayName`/`PidLidEmail3OriginalDisplayName` for the contact's second or third email address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work, but perhaps give it a try.

```
string email = await graphClient.Users[your_users_id].Request().Select("Mail").GetAsync().Mail;
```

To get the answer above, I used [this Get User documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) which briefly talks about Select statements. And [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) has a list of the properties which are available to the Select statement.